# Connecting to SQLExpress from Classic ASP application

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, connection-string, sql-server-express

I have a local SQLExpress database. I need to connect to this from a classic ASP web application.

I think my connection string is correct because when I test using a C# console app I'm able to connect and read data:

```c#
// C# Example app
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestData;Integrated Security=True";
var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

 con.Open();
 var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl", con);

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while(reader.Read())
 {
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(1)); // displays data
 }
```

However, when I use the same string in my ASP web application it fails:

```js
// ASP Web App
connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestData;Integrated Security=True";
Response.Write("connectionString:" + connectionString + "<br/>");
connection.Open(Application(connectionString)); // error
```

The Open method fails with:

> 0x80004005 - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

I also tried setting up a login for the SQL database and using a User Id and Password:

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestData;User Id=AspTest;Password=Test";
```

This fails in the same way.

How can I get my web app to connect to my database?

Comment: Try removing one of the backslashes from this: `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @markpsmith
I get the same result with Data Source=.\SQLExpress;

Comment: I don't understand how changing the connection string will help here, as you can see the connection string I used works with my C# sample.

Comment: Is possibly a 32 bit versus 64 bit issue? What is the c# running as in terms of architecture? If the server is 64 bit and the c# is running 32 bit for example, then is the web application enabled for 32 bit mode in the Application Pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Add a user for the local SQL database (including username and
   password)
2. Give user permissions to read, write, select (everything) items in DB (YMMV - it was required for my application)
3. Configure ODBC (32bit) (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) such that "SqlConnectString" uses SQL native client 11 to connect to (local)\SQLEXPRESS

   - Set SQL login credentials
   - Set default DB to be the testDB
4. Change the ASP connection code from:
   con.Open(Application("SqlConnectString"));
   to
   con.Open("DSN=SqlConnectString;User Id=[username];Password=[password]");

Your old timey ASP code now talks to SQL Express.

Answer (score 2):

If the ASP code you are showing is what you are actually using, Application(connectionString) most likely returns null/nothing as the application object is a dictionary. Have you tried to open the connection using the connection string directly:

```
connection.Open(connectionString);
```

The usual pattern is to assign Application("conectionString") = "your connection string" in global.asa and then use the follwing code to create the connection:

```
connection.Open(Application("connectionString"));
```

Also, you will need different connection strings for ASP and .NET as the previous answer indicated.

Comment: Be careful to only store the connection strings not the `ADODB.connection` object in `Application` or `Session` objects.

Comment: Not a big fan of using `Application("connectionString")` pattern because changes to the connection require the Application Pool to be restarted. Storing it in a `Session` object works better as a session can be easily abandoned.

Comment: Fair enough. My main point is that the code uses to connection string value as a lookup key in the application object.

Comment: No I agree. The `Application(connectionString)` is wrong, if they have the `connectionString` variable already defined the code sample just use that. Should be `connection.Open(connectionString);`. At the moment `Application` is going to look for a key called `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestData;Integrated Security=True` which makes no sense.

Comment: That was helpful, the Application object was empty.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; SERVER=MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MYDB; Uid=sa; Pwd=Pass!@#"